# Using a dictionary variable as parameters and values

Tags: ansible

I want to store a variable file into an object, and then use that object as the parameters for a command.  As a simple example, take the [`yum` command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html).

Essentially what I want to do this:

```
- name: Set yum attributes
  set_fact:
    module_attributes:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
- name: Do yum stuff
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    "{{ module_attributes}}"
```

I know this is possible by manually pulling all the attributes from the variable like below, but I'm hoping there's a way to offer up files with different options without having to list every parameter of the module.

```
- name: Set yum attributes
  set_fact:
    module_attributes:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
      exclude: kernel*,foo*
- name: Do yum stuff
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "{{ module_attributes.name }}"
    state: "{{ module_attributes.state }}"
    exclude: "{{ module_attributes.exclude }}"
    enablerepo: "{{ module_attributes.enablerepo}}"
    [...every other yum parameter...]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Wondering if this would work? `module_attributes: name=httpd state=latest`.  I am just basing that off of how module arguments are sent in when using `ansible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [explicitly addressed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-is-it-unsafe-to-bulk-set-task-arguments-from-a-variable) in the Ansible FAQ.

Yes, it's possible...

```yaml
- name: Set yum attributes
  set_fact:
    module_attributes:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
      exclude: kernel*,foo*

- name: Do yum stuff
  ansible.builtin.yum: "{{ module_attributes }}"
```

...but you'll get a warning whenever you do that because there are potential security concerns if you find yourself running the playbook on a compromised remote machine.

Comment: How generalized is this solution?  I'm playing around with various modules, and this doesn't seem to work for `set_fact`

Comment: It's pretty generalized. I think `set_fact` is probably a special case, but I'd have to poke at the source to be certain. To be fair, you asked about using this method with the `yum` module, and I think I've addressed that in this answer.

Comment: True, I was using yum to be a simplified example, but it also seems to work with `copy` so I think you are right that `set_fact` is unique.